# Evaluate a function in map

Tags: clojure

Let's say that I have the following map in Clojure:

```
(def person {:name "Jack" :say-hello #(print "hello")})
```

**Question 1:**
Is it possible to call the anonymous function of key :say-hello? How?

**Question 2**
Is it possible to instantiate / clone person vector with different values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(:say-hello person)` returns the function, so `((:say-hello person))` calls it.

The function is just a value like all other values, so you can pass it around and create new maps from it.